# What stops giant cruise ships toppling over in rough seas?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, kinematics, angular-momentum

A week ago, 2 of the most gigantic cruise ships in the world docked near my city. If you have seen one, or been on one, you will know how large they are.

[image: Giant Cruise Ship]

They look extremely unsafe to me, although obviously safety features must be built into them to stop them listing so far over that they seem to me to be in  danger of toppling completely in rough seas or strong sidewinds.

I want to avoid the engineering side and to stick to the physics, which is simply based around the control of the angular momentum of the large vessels.

So my assumptions first, then my question.

I have searched Google for schematics of the design, but nothing jumped out at me, except a greater than expected list of people asking much the same question as this one. [Are Cruise Ships Too Top Heavy?](http://www.cruiselawnews.com/2012/03/articles/sinking/are-cruise-ships-dangerously-top-heavy/) and [Why Mega Cruise Ships Are Unsafe](http://onlyinamericablogging.blogspot.com/2012/01/why-mega-cruise-ships-are-unsafe.html)

They have shallow, but wide, bottom surfaces.  Either they have small keel surfaces, or they are able to pull the keel inside the ship, because the draught in my city port is fairly shallow and yet they were able to get well inside the harbor.

I guess they carry a large amount of ballast, they certainly have the room for it.

I also guess that the top floors are made of light material, so as to lower the centre of gravity as much as possible.

They almost certainly have stabilisers, that act to reduce listing and basically do the job that a keel does for sailboats.

My question is, does anybody with experience in fluid dynamics or related areas know 
what keeps these giant ships stable in roll and reduces their potential to list to large angles in bad weather?

EDIT I am hoping for a physics based answer, but I realise it may be a question for another site, I will migrate no problem  if need be END EDIT

Comment: This blog is interesting http://onlyinamericablogging.blogspot.com/2012/01/why-mega-cruise-ships-are-unsafe.html

Comment: @annav thanks Anna, I put it on the post. I saw a few nautical guys comments saying they would not sail on them, but found no schematics or blueprints of the undersea sections.

Comment: Looks can be deceiving.  TL;DR:  the center-of-mass is nice and low down.

Comment: And BTW,  all ships do their best to stay perpendicular to storm waves.   A large wave which attacks directly from port or starboard will cause much greater roll, with far greater internal damage even if the hull doesn't pass the capsize angle.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft this is what you don't want your luxury cruise to turn out like  https://youtu.be/deX7R9RbmX0

Comment: @CarlWitthoft read the link. These large cruiseships use stabilizers, which means with a power failure they are at the mercy of the winds.

Comment: @anna stabilizers help, but sure sans power **all** non-sailing ships are unable to make headway, which is a BadThing.

Comment: They look top-heavy, but they are not. Suppose you took a row-boat, and put a few hundred pounds of cement bags in it. Then pile cardboard boxes on top several feet high. Same idea. It might look top-heavy, but if you try to push it over, the weight in the bottom will bring it back up.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey   as Floris  says, the metal comprising the underwater section is thicker and heavier than the rest. The ultimate test is, of course, have any mega ships actually toppled over from natural causes, none have, afaik.

Comment: @Acid: Every such boat is designed by engineers and you can be absolutely sure they've thought of that. You can be sure they have written a user's manual saying things like: putting more weight than XXX on decks YYY will "void the warranty". They know what they're doing.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey  yes and if one did tip over, it would make the news big time. The theory and tests are fine and I believe them fully, but I still would not like to have have been on the ship on the YouTube video on my comment to Carl, 6 comments above this one.

Comment: You should look up the term 'metacentric height' which will point you at a lot of information on how naval architects deal with stability.  Note that stabilisers *don't* do the same thing that the keel of a sailing vessel doss and *aren't* a safety feature: they serve to make the ship more comfortable but it must remain stable in the absence of power for fairly obvious reasons.  Finally this is nothing to do with fluid dynamics for the same reason: the ship must be stable while dead in the water.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some dimensions I was able to dig up (mostly from Wikipedia).

Draft of the Allure of the Seas: 31 ft (10 m)
Length: 1181 ft (360 m)
Beam at waterline: 47 m
Height: 72 m above waterline

Let's just draw the section based on these simple numbers:

[image]

Now if the center of gravity were in the middle of the ship (31 m above the water line), it would indeed not be very stable - any tilt beyond 25° would cause it to tip over:

[image]

However, there are several important factors:

1. The part of the hull below the surface is made of much thicker, stronger, heavier material than the superstructure
2. The engines etc. are all in the lowest levels
3. There is an active ballast system that allows pumping fuel and sea water from side to side to help maintain balance

I found one online test of the stability of the hull of this ship in a test facility, where they made a big hole in the side of an accurate model to see how it would fare: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ra4TkHOs4RE . While there are commercial interests at stake, nobody wants a marine disaster on their hands.

Comment: Thanks very much Floris, I had thought of two modern developments they could take advantage of, the active ballast idea you mention, but I thought the pumps would be too slow to respond, or vertical underwater thrusters, to force the down side back up.

Comment: @AcidJazz most of the active devices are there for comfort. If all engines fail the only thing left is the form stability which requires the low center of gravity. This is where light superstructures come into play. Worth estimating how much the cog shifts when all passengers go to the top deck. 200 thousand tonnes is a lot of mass- 6000 passengers are a few % of that at most.

Comment: "the part of the hull below the surface is made of much heavier material": indeed, they even put a massive metal bit there called keel. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keel . Excellent answer btw +1

Comment: @Numrok thanks. As far as I know, these large ocean liners often don't have a real keel, just ballast. If you google"cruise ship sectional drawing" you will see this clearly.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt it is all fluid dynamics.  The have to stay upright even with dead engines.  If the integral of the lever below the water line is bigger than above then it should stay upright.  Ballast at the bottom goes a long way as it has a long lever.  Stuff like engines below deck tends to be heavy anyway.  Weight is not a big deal as they are not going up hill.  They need a low draft to get into port.  If you looked at an aircraft carrier out of water it would also appear top heavy.

Let assume a ship with 2/3 above water line.  Break the up in 9 units.  6 above and 3 below.
Naturally lightest stuff on top and heavy below. 
In this example the net lever above is 45 and below 180.

```
Height Weight Lever 
6      1       6
5      2      10
4      3      12
3      4      12
2      5      10
1      5       6
net           56
1      10     20
2      20     40
3      40    120
net          180
```

Imagine that is a teeter-totter with 3 fat kids on one side and 6 skinny on the other.  Even if the skinny kids have twice the lever the fat kids still dominate.

Since it pivots on the hull and not the center line the bottom loses leverage as it starts to list.  So a narrow hull at the water line is a good thing.

Comment: Your aircraft carrier point is spot on, I should have thought of that, I saw a quote that said these ships "snap" back to vertical so quickly that passengers complain it's worse than the original listing effect was on their stomachs. Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: Even though fat kids may look twice as heavy as skinny kids, due to their similar bone structure, which has a higher density than fat, they rarely are. Sorta like cruise ships and aircraft carriers, really. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it many seagoing vessels also use gyroscopes spinning on a vertical axis attached to the main components of the vessel's structure to null out much of the motion on the vessel's roll axis. Gyroscopes are also popular among motor yachts. I'm not Shure if they're used on giant cruise ships or not but, gyros are one way of providing stability, and safety.

Comment: well, this does somehow miss the point, gyroscopes may give safety in the navigation-sense, but they definitely do not stabilize in a way meant in the question

Answer (score -2):

a large lever attached with a ship will give a huge effort on other side that it can heat the water by driving an engine made of dc motor and emf give to heating element which operate on dc voltage  so it may work on either side to produce steam engine can produce electricity at a constant speed to provide for grid operation.

Comment: I cannot parse this answer and from what I can understand, I don't see how this answers the question. Could you maybe rewrite and indicate how it answers the question?